# Shut down rails server once it's been daemonized?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, application-server

In Ubuntu, I can run a rails server in the background as a daemon by passing in the --daemon option;

```
bundle exec puma -e production -b unix:///var/run/my_app.sock --daemon
```

However, how do I gracefully shut this daemonized process down? It's not a simple matter of `crtl + c` anymore :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use puma control `pumactl`, it processes monitor and controller.

and then you can use it like this to stop

```
bundle exec pumactl -P /var/run/puma.pid stop
```

OR

```
pumactl -C unix://var/run/my_app_pumactl.sock [status|restart|halt|stop]
```

Comment: This did work fine, but now, after running `pumactl - C unix<path> stop` I get this error message `Bad response from server: 500`